# Appending custom Query to a Wordpress specific menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm creating a WP menu, which should take the user to the current page, and just append a query to end of it.

So, for example I'm on a custom page:
example.com/group/fans

So the current menu items which links to:

1. /?query1
2. /?query2
3. /?query3

Should be appended to the current page:
example.com/group/fans/?query1

And same thing for different pages, with the **Same** menu items.

I've searched for many solutions but couldn't find one, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `post_link` filter?  I think something like below might be what you are looking for:

```
add_filter('post_link', function ($link) {

  $pattern = 'group/fans';
  $is_custom_query = strpos($link, $pattern) !== false;

  if ($is_custom_query) {
    return add_query_arg([
      'query1' => 'someValue',
      'query2' => 'someValue2'
    ], $link);
  }

  return $link;
});
```